# Changing currency on checkout with WooCommerce Multilingual Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to implement currency change on checkout with [WooCommerce Multilingual Plugin](https://wpml.org/documentation/related-projects/woocommerce-multilingual/). I need a country with COP and the rest of countries with USD. First I tried to use the wcml_client_currency hook.

```php
function modify_client_currency( $currency ) {
  $country = WC()->customer->get_billing_country();
  if ($country === 'CO') {
    return 'COP';
  } else {
    return 'USD';
  }
}

add_filter( 'wcml_client_currency', 'modify_client_currency', 10, 1 );
```

If I start with Colombia selected, the currency is in COP, but if I change to another country, the currency stay on COP. I need to change the country again to see the change.

I tried another approach with the woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review and analyzing how the multilingual plugin works.

```php
function action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review( $post_data ) {
  // This part will change dynamically based on the country contained in $post_data
  $currency = 'COP';

  global $woocommerce_wpml;
  $woocommerce_wpml->multi_currency->set_client_currency($currency);

  global $woocommerce, $current_user;
  if(empty($woocommerce->session->data) && empty($current_user->ID)){
      $woocommerce->session->set_customer_session_cookie(true);
  }
  do_action('wcml_switch_currency', $currency );

  WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
}

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 10, 1);
```

With this approach I have exactly the same problem, I need to change the country twice to see the currency change.